# SWIFT CoreData storage in one VC and retrieval in another VC

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So, i'm going to preface this with the classic i'm a novice programmer.

Firstly, i have to give you a basic rundown of how this thing works.

I've been building out an app where i use an ActionSheet and an AlertViewController to intake data, and save it with a saveItem() function where the 'for loop' takes in the ActionSheet output and then uses that as a marker to store the data thats taken in from the AlertViewController.

Well, i have checked (in this initial VC) if the PList data has been saved (and it has!). But when i go from that VC to (the right) to a TableView, then from that TableView to another VC with information (this is the VC i need to retrieve the plist data from). When i load the view, it says that the plist data is empty. I'm halfway thinking that it's a problem with the ManagedObjectContext. But i'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's very difficult to debug an implementation we cannot see. What's the simplest example you can build to demonstrate this problem? It sounds like you might be using a different managed object context for each controller and never merging data between then but that's a wild guess without more information.

Comment: You say you're using Core Data, but then you talk about plists. Plists and Core Data are different ways of storing data, and if you're storing an item one way then you're not storing it the other way. You need to edit your original post and provide the relevant code along with a description of what you expect it to be doing and what it's doing instead.

Comment: BTW, if you're a novice programmer then Core Data is likely way over your head. It's a very powerful framework but also quite complex and difficult to learn. plists or user defaults would be a better place to start until you learn more.